# Unable to Execute Javascript Code In A PHP File

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that inputs data into mysql database. Now I want to display a javascript message upon the successful insertion of the data.However I am not able to execute the javascript code.

Below is my code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>

       <script type="text/javascript">
            function run(){
                alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "datacentre";


$first=$_POST['firstname'];//this values comes from html file after submitting 

$last=$_POST['lastname'];

$dept= $_POST['department'];

$unit= $_POST['unit'];

$request=$_POST['request'];

$purpose=$_POST['purposebuttons']; 

$accessedby = $_POST['personbuttons'];

 $description=$_POST['description']; 

$accessdate = $_POST['date-time'];


/* Get Current Date and Time for the bookking_time field */
$booking_time=new DateTime();
$booking_time = $booking_time -> format("Y-m-d H:i:s");


// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname , 3306);
    

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

 //mysql_select_db("$database", $con);
 $sql= "INSERT INTO data_centre_users (first_name,last_name,department, unit, request, purpose , accessed_by, 

description,booking_time,access_time)
VALUES ('$first','$last','$dept', '$unit','$request','$purpose', '$accessedby' ,'$description', NOW() , '$accessdate')"; 

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

  /* Calling the javascript code */
    echo '<script> run(); </scrit>';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo '<script> run(); </scrit>'; - is misspelled the script closing tag

Comment: you can directly do like this. echo '<script> alert("Data Inserted Successfully"); </script>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check spelling of `script`

```
 echo '<script> run(); </scrit>';
                         ^^^^^^
```

It would be

```
 echo '<script> run(); </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The script end tag is misspelled. Update it as follows:

```
echo '<script> run(); </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled `</scrit>` it must be `</script>` .

you can try this:

```
   echo '<script> alert("Data Inserted Successfully"); </script>'
```